# How do I fix this Method to properly count the number of times an iteration within another Method has been called?

Tags: java

I have this method:

```
    private double iterate(double n) throws InvalidInput {
        int a=1, b=2;
        int result = 0;
        double counter = n;
        if (n>=1) {
            if(n==1)return a;
            if(n==2)return b;
            for(int i = 3; i <= counter; i++) {                                        
                result = a+(2*b);
                a=b;
                b = result;
                this.getEfficiency();
            }                
        }   else{
                throw new InvalidInput();
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I have a variable declared in the main class (efficiency) and a method that I am using to count the number of calls to this method

```
    private int getEfficiency() {            
        efficiency++;
        return efficiency;
    }
```

The problem is if, say I input 5 for n on the first operation, it will populate the efficiency field with 1 the first time and then +4 every time thereafter.

Just for further clarification, the loop is being run 1 time less than n (with the exception of when I input 1 or 2 for n) and I am trying to figure out why the first time I run the loop I am getting +1 instead of n-1.

Code that calls the method

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(nField.getText());
        //Try Catch for Iterate Radio Button
        if (iterateBtn.isSelected()){
            try {
            int efficiency = getEfficiency();
            double result = iterate(n);
            rField.setText(Double.toString(result));
            eField.setText(Integer.toString(efficiency));
            }
            catch (InvalidInput ex) {
            }
        }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is the call for the method in an incorrect place, you should have:

```
private double iterate(double n) throws InvalidInput {
    int a=1, b=2;
    int result = 0;
    double counter = n;
    if (n>=1) {
        if(n==1)return a;
        if(n==2)return b;
        for(int i = 3; i <= counter; i++) {                                        
            result = a+(2*b);
            a=b;
            b = result;
        }                
    }   else{
            throw new InvalidInput();
    }
    this.getEfficiency();
    return result;
}
```

Comment: That actually makes it count incorrectly. Instead of getting n-1 for efficiency it is simply adding 2 to the efficiency counter.

Comment: Can you post the code where you call the iterate method?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so after reading what user jclozano said and looking into the code that he asked me to post, I have found that his telling me that my call to getEfficiency method being in the place was not too far off.

The extra code that I posted had the call to getEfficiency above the call to my iterate method. I moved the method to be called after the iterate method and it now works properly.

Here is the updated code that shows what fixed it.

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        int n = Integer.parseInt(nField.getText());
        //Try Catch for Iterate Radio Button
        if (iterateBtn.isSelected()){
            try {
            double result = iterate(n);        //I swapped this line
            int efficiency = getEfficiency();  //with this line
            rField.setText(Double.toString(result));
            eField.setText(Integer.toString(efficiency));
            }
            catch (InvalidInput ex) {
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private double iterate(double n) throws InvalidInput{
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
        result = this.getEfficiency();
    }
    return result;
}
```

You need to initialize the `efficiency` to 0.

```
int efficiency = 0;
```

to the main class.

Comment: I stated in my post that I had already initialized efficiency in my main class.
If you look below I actually answered my own question, I I just wasn't looking in the right place.

Comment: With what value have you initialized it?

Comment: It was initialized to 0.

Comment: I did not as I found my mistake already, although the result variable being changed to the efficiency variable would not give me the result desired from the looks of it. Doing that would change my result variable to to the number of times the loop was ran.

Comment: After i saw your other part of code i understood what you were looking for. Glad you resolved it.